# Deleting "My documents" history

Tags: windows-xp, file-history

Using Windows XP, my file history is shown under <kbd>start</kbd>→<kbd>my documents</kbd>.

I can delete files one at a time by right-click and selecting <kbd>delete</kbd>. I want to be able to remove multiple files at a time from my `Recent File History`?

Comment: Pleas [edit] your question to include the operating system. I assume it is Windows? Which version?

Comment: in Windows XP, in the RUN dialog you can type `%recent%`. This shows up the list of all recent files. Select all and delete.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this page](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-clear-or-delete-my-recent-documents-in-windows/) to see how to do it in Windows 7, 8, Vista & XP:

> ***Clear Recent Documents Windows XP & Vista***
>
> 1. First, right-click on the Start Button and choose Properties:
> 2. You’ll now be in the Start Menu and Taskbar properties dialog box. You should already be on the Start Menu tab. Go ahead and click on the Customize button.
> 3. At the bottom, you’ll see a section called Recent Documents. Click Clear List to clear the most recent list of documents. If you do not want Windows to record your recent documents at all, uncheck the List my most recently opened documents box. That’s it!
>
> ***Clear Recent Documents Windows 7 & 8***
>
> 1. If you right-click on the Start Menu, choose Properties, click on the Start Menu tab and then click on Customize, you’ll see a checkbox for Recent Items towards the bottom.
> 2. If you go back to the Customize dialog where you enabled Recent Documents, you’ll see two options at the bottom for Start Menu Size:The item we are interested in is Number of recent items to display in Jump Lists. Go ahead and set that to 0 and Windows will no longer show the list of recently opened documents. When you right-click on a program from your taskbar, the list will be gone.
> 3. windows still store the history To prevent Windows from storing the history altogether, you have to right-click on Start, go to Properties again and click on the Start Menu tab. This time don’t click on Customize!
>
>    You will see under the Privacy section a checkbox for Store and display recently opened items in the Start menu and the taskbar. Go ahead and uncheck that box and now Windows will no longer store the history.